# IAB.close() called but it was already closed

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

When i build solution in cordova ios platform it is successfully built.But When i run it using Xcode a white screen appears and beyond that nothing happens.
Following is the output in Xcode.Can anyone help me in here.Thanks in advance.

**2020-06-03 15:00:40.803686+0530 MyApplicationName[78976:5376253] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 3.167033ms
2020-06-03 15:00:40.803831+0530 MyApplicationName[78976:5376253] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 308.578968ms
2020-06-03 15:00:41.721338+0530 MyApplicationName[78976:5376253] IAB.close() called but it was already closed.
2020-06-03 15:00:41.721480+0530 MyApplicationName[78976:5376253] IAB.close() called but it was already closed.
2020-06-03 15:00:43.025091+0530 MyApplicationName[78976:5376253] Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 866 ms**

following is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "SRIonicApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "apk": "1.2.0",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.10",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "iso": "5.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": "0.0.2",
    "node-js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^3.6.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "config": {
    "ionic_copy": "./custom_scripts.js"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "call-number": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Following are the methods

```
    ref: any;

    openBrowserForUrl(url) {
            console.log('->openBrowserForUrl ' + url);
//this is the place where browser closes
            this.closeBrowser(false);
            // this.clearWebViewCookies();
            let randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
            this.exitData = {
                status: null,
                data: {
                    usrId: '', usrName: '', usrCompany: '', url: "",
                    jwt: '', key: ''
                }
            };
            //CONFIG.BACKEND_URL 'https://au.staging.mobility.dtz.com' CONFIG.BACKEND_URL

            this.ref = this.iab.create(CONFIG.BACKEND_URL + url + '?rand=' + randNumber + '&language=EN', '_blank', 'hidden=yes,location=no,clearcache=yes,closebuttoncaption=Back,clearsessioncache=yes,enableViewportScale=yes,hidespinner=yes');
            this.addListenersToBrowser();
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.showBrowser();
            }, 6000);
        }
        closeBrowser(shouldInform: boolean) {
            console.log('->closeBrowser');
            if (this.ref) {
                this.ref.close();
            }
            this.exitBrowser(shouldInform);
        }
```

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: @Sébastien i shared package.json. Is that enough ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not code. Please show the code  where you call `close()`

Comment: @Sébastien I have  added.Please check.

Comment: I still don't see what `showBrowser()` and `exitBrowser()` do.